# Page Breaks display incorrectly and other Print Out Appearance issues

Tags: export, pdf-format, printing

[image: Comparison]

on the left is Mathematica with its Page Break on display and on the right the PDF file with worng breaking. How is this happening?
The Page Break has been automaticly generated and if i were to add my own Page Break, Mathematica doest display some of its automaticly generated Page Breaks anymore. I realy need these to work Properly and be able to set my own and see the generated Breaks.

here is another issue:

[image: Comparison 2]

Left is again the view i get from Prinout, right is export.

It makes no difference if i use "Save as PDF" or hit Print and print it to a virtual PDF-Printer.

Thanks